# InfoPath - Text Field limitation Workaround

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath-2007

Does anyone know of a workaround for the field size limitation of 255 characters? I have an InfoPath form which is tied to a workflow. I send the infopath fields to the workflow but because it has a limit of 255 it truncates the data. I would like to somehow be able to send all the data to the workflow.

Workflow Text Field Limit of 255 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292551(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of 255 characters applies to a single line text field only. Use a multi-line text field instead, which can take way more than 255 characters.

Comment: I checked the multi-line checkbox and I don't see a multi-line control. What are you referring to? Where is it?